# JavaScript/jQuery script looping 3 times without a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get a notification box to pop up on errors/successes and then hide after 5 seconds. The problem is that it shows up, hides, then repeats 3 times. It's annoying and I'm sure it will bug the user.

I thought maybe my javascript was bad, so I tried jquery, still the same result.

```
function ajaxObj(meth, url) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(meth, url, true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
        return true;
    }
}


   function login() {
    var u = _("user").value;
    var p = _("pass").value;
    var status = _("status");

    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "login_script.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajax.responseText !== "success"){
        status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        _('status').className = "nNote nFailure hideit";
        var svalue = _('status').innerHTML;
        _('status').innerHTML = svalue + '<span style="float:right; margin-right:20px; font-size:10px;" onclick="hideStatus()"> X </span>';
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#status').slideDown(1000).delay( 5000 ).slideUp(1000);
         });
      }
    };
    ajax.send(
        "u=" + u
        + "&p=" + p);
}
```

If you want to see what it's doing, go to [this site](http://lucienconsulting.com/brick-academy/) and click "login"

Comment: You're not checking the `readyState` of `ajax`.

Comment: @Jack: there is no check for the readyState in http://lucienconsulting.com/brick-academy/js/functions/login.js

Comment: @Dr.Molle but there is in  http://lucienconsulting.com/brick-academy/js/ajax.js ;)

Comment: @Jack SO users should not have to follow your links and tear apart your site to find relevant code. Post all relevant code here.

Comment: `login()` doesn't use `ajaxReturn()`, so it doesn't check the readyState.

Comment: @Jack: the function with the check doesn't have any meaning, you did not execute this function somewhere

Comment: Please get off the ajax thing. I'll post the entire ajax part above. Seriously...

Comment: I determined the problem using the Javascript debugger. I set a DOM breakpoint on attribute change of the `status` DIV. The breakpoint triggered, and I looked at `ajax`, and its `readyState` property was set to 2.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why don't you just use `$.ajax()`, and let it take care of this for you?

Comment: Because I wrote 80% of the code of the entire site not using javascript.

Comment: @Jack thanks for posting relevant code. Yes, you have a function which does check ready state, BUT YOU NEVER CALL IT. You are setting your `onreadystatechange` to a completely different function WHICH DOES NOT CHECK ready state.

Comment: You should call `encodeURIComponent` on `u` and `p`.

Comment: Something along these lines should work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/G5nuA/1/

Comment: Try to call stop() to immediately stop previous (ongoing) animation, like $('#status').stop().slideDown(1000).delay( 5000 ).slideUp(1000);

Comment: @Barmar why would i uriencode a posted value?

Comment: In case the username or password contains special characters. For instance, if the password contains `&`, it needs to be %-encoded or it will be treated as a parameter delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
    if(ajax.responseText !== "success"){
```

to:

```
    if(ajaxReturn(ajax) && ajax.responseText !== "success"){
```

You have this function for checking whether the AJAX request is complete, but you forgot to call it.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `ajaxReturn()` and check the values of `x.readyState` and `x.status`.

Comment: So why is it returning a 2 and not a 4?

Comment: Wait, that still does not make sense. If the readyState is 2, it should not return as true.

Comment: @Jack, a reqeust made with XMLHTTPRequest goes through various states. The function assigned to `onreadystatechange` is called each time the state changes. As described at http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate when a request enters state 2 it means the headers for the response have been received. A later state change should result in the function being called again with a state of 4 (DONE). `ajaxResponse` should return false until the request is DONE (in state 4), thereby keeping your response-processing code from executing until it has been completely received.

Comment: That's why I said it does not make sense. If it's returning 2, then it should return false and not even start to run the functions below. They are not fully opening but there is a flicker and it is running them even though its returning 2.

Comment: I went through the script step by step and when it returned 4 it did not show how it was supposed to.

Comment: Status is 200 for 2, 3 and 4

Answer (score 2):

leave the function when `ajax.readyState!==4`

You are calling this function when the onreadystatechange-event fires, but this event will fire multiple times(when `readyState===4` the request is complete)

But this question is tagged with "jquery", you better  use `jQuery.ajax()`